# Scrollbar bottom automatically when click on add in table

Tags: angular

I want to sroll the srollbar at bottom when add button clicked in table in angular 6.

The add button include functionality  of add.

Comment: Hello Nilofar, what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

I have created one screen which include the table with add, delete, edit bitton. I want to add the new row at the same time srollbar should b go to bottom  of page till the newly added row.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're structuring your form.
What you'll have to do is, assuming you already have an event listener function to the `add` button, you'll add a function that redirects the user to an anchored div, title, or whatever unique trait each form might have.